# how to find relative path to symbolic linked files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to find relative path to all symbolic linked files. My code doesn't work

```
find ./aaa/ -type l -ls
```

Comment: What do you mean relative path? Relative to what?

Comment: to current_file/aaa

Comment: If you remove `-ls` it'll show relative paths to all symbolic links, not sure if that's what you're asking though.

Comment: A symoblic link to `./aaa` could exist anywhere on the filesystem, so you'll need to `find / ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your commands seems fine. If it doesn't work check the path. You know "./aaa/"  means search in current directory under "aaa" folder. Make sure you are in the same directory or change to absolute path for example: /home/user/aaa/

Comment: still shows full path like home/lenovo/aaa/bbb/file.txt not bbb/file.txt